# Encountered arithmetic overflow error using decimal datatype in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, math, overflow, decimal

I have a column declared as decimal(4,4). Currently it stores 0.0400 as the value. Now I need to update the value stored from 0.0400 to 9.95.I used the following query :

```
Update <tablename>
set <columnname>= 9.95
where <condition>
```

When I try to execute, I get the following error :
*Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.*

Kindly help.

Answer (score 5):

Defining a column as `decimal(4,4)` is the equivalent of saying

> I will have 4 digits in total, of which 4 come after the decimal point

To represent `9.95`, you'd need to store it as `9.9500` to satisfy the '4 decimal places' condition. But this now exceeds the 'max 4 digits' condition and so can't be converted.

You'd need at least `decimal(5, 4)` to store 9.95 as a decimal in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you write `decimal(4,4)`, what the database hears is:

- There are four digits total
- All four of them are behind the decimal separator

So a `decimal(4,4)` can store the range `0.0000` to `0.9999` (and its negative equivalent).  But `9.95` is outside that range, so it will return an error.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue few years ago, here is my understanding.

Decimal(TotalDigitsIncludingDecimal,DecimalPlaces)

Eg: Value = 50.05 declare Decimal(4,2)
Eg: Value = 5000.0005 declare Decimal(8,4)

Answer (score 1):

Decimal(6,2) means:

At most 4 digits to the left of the decimal point, since you can have 2 to the right of the decimal point. (even if you don't see them, or use them)

It is VERY wrong to say "you can have 6 digits total".
12345 is less than 6 digits total. But it'll overflow.

I'm not sure why SQL didn't just make it "Decimal(left, right)" and you would instantly see the limits you can store there.